# Repository for organizing company SQL statements?

Tags: sql-server

We have a few people here that use SQL and have quite a few queries we each individually use and share.  I'm wondering if there's a solution to store all of these statements in a central repository where they can be used and copied but not modified. We did consider a folder on a network drive and storing the .sql files, but were wondering if there was a better solution out there.

Comment: We use tortoiseSVN. People will be able to change/improve the files but you have a log of changes. Also, everybody has a local copy.

Comment: Go with Git - it's complex so your devs will love it :-)

Comment: The world moves towards git. It offers many more advantages against any other version control system. But really, any proper version control system is better than a shared network folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used SVN for this, seems to be quite popular as several companies I've spent time with used it. You should be able to control who can and cannot write/update files, as well as who can see what. And one of the more popular clients is Tortoise, as vercelli mentions.

Comment: This look like the perfect solution for our needs, as well as our code base!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use source control and create a repo for storing scripts in a similar way to the way you store code. However, I'm a big fan of WIKIs for this- it also gives you a platform for other documentation.

Check out Confluence.

Answer (score 1):

Besides source control repositories, we've also used Sharepoint for SQL scripts. You can access it just like a network drive too.